# How to find the expected value and median of a chi square distribution with $12$ dof in R?

Tags: r, self-study, expected-value, median, chi-squared-distribution

How can I find the expected value and median of $X\sim \chi^2$ with degrees of freedom of $12\,$? The information I get from every other source, I find, is confusing. I am using R.

Comment: Is *X* the probability density function for the chi-square distribution ? Does the Wikipedia page answer your question ?  [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)

Answer (score 4):

The mean of a $\chi^2$ random variable is equal to the degrees of freedom. The median has no close form afaik, you can get it in R from the inverse cumulative distribution function (aka the quantile function) evaluated at $0.5$:

```r
qchisq(0.5, dof)
```